# How to split a value field into more fields in crystal reports?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm developing crystal reports on visual studio 2017 and I'm exporting crystal reports into pdf using c# .net. and I have connected my database through OLEDB ADO and I have wrote query in command field to display the values for Selected rooms column.

In command,my column name is Rooms_allocated.

For example:

### I'm getting the result like:

```
Selected rooms: value1,value2,value3,value4
But I want to split the values like:
Selected rooms:value1
               value2
               value3
               value4
```

So In crystal reports how to split the values?

Answer (score 0):

formula1

```
split({@yourfield},":")[1] +":"
```

formula2

```
replace(split({@yourfield},":")[2],",",CHR(13))
```

- place them next to each other on the canvas
- right click formula 2
- select format field
- click common tab
- check the box next to Can Grow
- click OK

My results below

[image]

Comment: But in main report preview,I'm getting subscript must be between 1 and size of the array.

Comment: are there times when there is no value in the field?